Android Studio Hiding Important Buttons
I am using Android Studio with the new UI (Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1, windows 11).  Just switched from Jellyfish (old UI).  After many hours of bewilderment, I have discovered that buttons are hidden until the mouse gets close.  The minimize and the options menu are particularly missing in this pic.

Here are the buttons, visible only when the mouse is nearby:

But how do you know to put the mouse close to where the button should be if that button is hidden?
And if you do know where the button is, you have to do an extra mouse movement: one to get the button to appear, and another to click on the button you want.
Is there a way to simply show all the buttons all the time?
I found a bug report at the intellij bug-tracker, but the responses there seem extremely lackluster considering the badness of this ui.  And of course, there is no solution yet.  Perhaps others here have found a work-around.

Thanks to @Anton Malyshev for guiding me to the answer.  For those who don't want to click on a link and hunt down the answer (and in case the link disappears in the future), here's the solution.
In Android Studio, Preferences -> Advanced Settings -> Tool Windows (scroll waaaay down!)  and make sure that "Always show tool window header icons in the new UI" is checked.  Here's a picture.


There is a solution in your Youtrack link: the option is called "Always show tool window header icons in the new UI", it's in Advanced settings.
